.Net 8 application on linux container trying to have Db2 server connection throwing "GSKit Error: 201" could not be loaded
I'm trying to connect to DB2 server from .Net 8 application.
hosted application on In Linux Docker container.
When trying to test connection getting getting below exception.
"ERROR [42724] [IBM] SQL10013N The specified library "GSKit Error: 201" could not be loaded.  SQLSTATE=42724"
I'm using nuget package "Net.IBM.Data.Db2-lnx" Version="8.0.0.300" which have GSKit:
Here are the environment variables i set
ENV DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH=/app/clidriver
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/clidriver/lib
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/clidriver/lib/icc
ENV PATH=$PATH:/app/clidriver/bin


clidriver is looking for a stash file. Is the Db2-server also running in the same container, or is the Db2-server remote (outside) of the container?  Please edit your question to show the connection string in full (redact any password value and userid value with * ).
